# rare error between alert and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script where I do a consultation with ajax . The problem , however stupid it may seem, it works only if I put an alert at the end ( as in the first code)

```
$(window, document, undefined).ready(function () {
 $("#ingresar").click(function(){

 if($("#usuario").val() === "") {
        alert("Debe ingresar un nombre de usuario");
        return;
    }else if($("#password").val() === "") {
    alert("Debe ingresar su contraseña");
    return;

}

$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data:$("#form1").serialize(),
        success: function (msg){

            if(msg == "1") {
                window.location.assign("../index_admin.php");    
            }else{
                alert("Usuario inexistente, verifique sus datos");
            }

        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("MAL" + msg);
        }
    });
  alert("");  /**If this does not work bag**/
});
});
```

if I delete the last alert ( alert ( " " ) ) does not work ajax

```
$(window, document, undefined).ready(function () {
 $("#ingresar").click(function(){

 if($("#usuario").val() === "") {
    alert("Debe ingresar un nombre de usuario");
    return;
}else if($("#password").val() === "") {
alert("Debe ingresar su contraseña");
return;

}

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "login.php",
    data:$("#form1").serialize(),
    success: function (msg){

        if(msg == "1") {
            window.location.assign("../index_admin.php");    
        }else{
            alert("Usuario inexistente, verifique sus datos");
        }

    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("MAL" + msg);
    }
});

});
});
```

Comment: `alert` is blocking code. Just don't use it.

Comment: if I delete the last alert ( alert ( " " ) ) does not work ajax

Comment: Sorry for the error :(. if I delete the last alert ( alert ( " " ) ) does not work ajax

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: run this code: error: function (msg) {
        alert("MAL" + msg);
    }

Comment: I solved with "return false;" instead of an alert ... Thanks!

Comment: To find out what is wrong, you should put in console.log statements throughout the code to see where it is getting to. Also, you should wrap the code in your success and error functions in try{} catch(error) {} blocks and log out the error cases incase what is returned is not what you think. Once you have done that, you should have a clearer picture of where your code is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with "return false;" instead of an alert...